# Why am I getting a member function error in my codeigniter library?

Tags: codeigniter, php

This is the code that I'm running:

```
class Auth {
//put your code here

var $ci;

function __construct()
{
    $this->ci =& get_instance();
    $this->ci->load->library('session');
}

function Login($param)
{    
    // Get user from database           
    $this->ci->load->model('User_model');
    $user = $this->ci->user_model->getuserbyemail($param["email"]);
```

(or at least the part  that I'm running)

I'm getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function
>   getuserbyemail() on a non-object in
>   C:\Users\Piers\Documents\Projects\dithinsi\application\libraries\Auth.php
>   on line 28

Line 28 is the the bottom line of the code above.

Is it because I'm not handling the `$ci` variable properly?

Comment: Did you copy the User_model file from another file and forget to rename the class?

Comment: Doesnt `$this->ci` return the User_Model instance as opposed to storing it internally? Try `$users = $this->ci->load->model('User_model'); $users->getuserbyemail();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the `user_model` property is undeclared.

According to [Codeigniter manual](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#loading), the property name of a model object equals to the value of the argument given to `model()` method.

In PHP variable names are case sensitive. `User_model` does not equal to `user_model`.

Try what happens with:

```
$user = $this->ci->User_model->getuserbyemail($param["email"]);
```

Comment: Absolutely right. I was treating it like a library. Doh!